# Section/Internal link - leave margin above on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap on a site and on the desktop view I leave the Navigation bar stuck at the top.  I'm wanting the section links to leave this gap in place (`60px` I believe).  So when I have a...

`<a href="#SectionID">Section Link</a>`

Is there a way to have it respect the `60px` that the top navigation bar consumes?

*NOTE:* If it's relevant the site is currently using Bootstrap 2, but I'm in the process of moving it to 3.  If the solution is different between the two...or if one version inherently does this I'd love to know the differences.

***EDIT:*** I'm wanting the element I'm linking, to have the gap above it not the actual `a` tag itself.  Also, I could care less if it's a `JS` or `CSS` solution.  If someone has JavaScript disabled I'm fine with the slight annoyance of it's current appearance for them.

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="margin-top:60px"` to your  tag - this will lower its position

or place it inside a `div` tag
ex:

```
<div style="top:60px">
<a href="#SectionID">Section Link</a>
</div>
```

***EDIT***

I hope i understand the question now, if not, sorry

you can put this javascript on the page

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('#') != -1){
window.scrollBy(0, -60)
}
```

this way, the page finds the desired section then scrolls down 60px as soon as it loads, making the section header appear below the Nav bar

Comment: I've added info the question.  I'm wanting the linked element to respect the nav-bar margin.  Not the `a` tag.  Sorry for the confusion.